# On a 3D Terrain, Given a 3D Line, Find the Intersection Point Between the Line and the Terrain

Tags: c#, graphics

I have a grid of 3D terrain, where each of the coordinate `(x,y,z)` of each grid are known. Now, I have a monotonously increasing/ decreasing line, which its start point is also known. I want to find the point where the terrain and the line meets. What is the algorithm to do it?

[image]

What I can think of is to store the coordinate of the 3D terrain in a `nxn` matrix. And then I would segmentize the line based on the grid in the terrain. I would then start with the grid that is the nearest to the line, and then try to compute whether that plane intersects with the line, if yes, then get the coordinate and exit. If no, then I would proceed to the next segment.

But is my algorithm the best, or the most optimum solution? Or is there any existing libraries that already do this?

Comment: Halfrelated to the Question: If you used to triangles to represent your grid quads, you can avoid problems when the four corners of a node do not lie in a plane (think of a square folded at its diagonal). Especially if you are using OpenGL for the visualization.

Comment: @sum1stolemyname, I thought of that too. But my point is to find the most efficient algorithm to get the intersection between the terrain and the line, since rectangular grid is ideal to be repesented in 2x2 matrix ( for the ease of accessing which grid), that's why I'm using rectangular grid.

Comment: the x,y coordinates of the grid vertices are regularly spaced, right? That's what I understand from "grid", but just wanted to check. And the z of each vertex is arbitrary but is known.

Comment: @LarsH, yes, x, y are regularly spaced.

Answer (score 1):

Not directly and optimisation, just a few hints:

If your grid is large, it might be worthwhile to build an [octree](http://www.flipcode.com/archives/Introduction_To_Octrees.shtml) from your terrain in order to quickly reduce the number of grid nodes you have to check your line against. This can be more efficient in a huge grid( like 512*512 ndoes) since only the leafnodes your ray is passing through have to be considered.

Additionally, the Octree can be used as a means to decide wich parts of your grid are visible and therefore have to be drawn, by checking which leave-nodes are in the viewing frustum.

There is a catch, though: building the Octree has to be done in advance, taking some time, and the tree is static. It can not be easyly modified after it has been constructes, since a modification in one node might affect several other nodes, not necessarily adjacent ones.

However, if you do not plan to modify your grid once it is created an octree will be helpful.

**UPDATE**

Now that i understand how you are planning to store your grid, i believe space partitioning will be an efficent way to find  the nearest neighbour of the intersection line.

Finding the nearest Neighbour linearly has a runtime complexity of O(N), while space-partitioning appoaches have an average runtime complexity if O(log N).

Comment: Not sure why you suggest octree, but since I already have a matrix of z coordinate, I can easily check which segment of the line is falling into, isnt' it?

Comment: @ngu soon hui: I am not completely sure if i understand how a grid can be represented in a 2x2 Matrix. A 2x2-Matrix can store exactly 4 values - 2 rows by two columns. Could you Clarify?

I suggested an octree to quickly eliminate areas of your terrain which don't lie close enough to your line to be intersecting it, in order to produce more 'early outs', thus reducing the amount of line segments you'd need to check.

Answer (score 1):

A different approach would be to triangulate the terrain grid to produce a set of facets and then intersect the line with those.

Obviously you'd need to do some optimisations like only checking those facets that intersect the bounding box of the line. You can do a quite cheap/quick facet bounding box to line bounding box check which will discount most of the triangles in the terrain very quickly.

If you arrange your triangles in to an octree (as @sum1stolemyname suggested but for the points) then this checking can be done from the "top down" and you should be able to discount whole sections of the the terrain with a single calculation.

Comment: the thing with the triangulation is that I would have to check every single triangle to see whether it misses or hit, won't that take a long time? You said one can check the facet that intersect the line bounding box, but I fail to see how this actually optimize the thing

Comment: @Ngu - Sorry, you need to do a facet bounding box to line bounding box check which is quite quick and you'll be able to discount most of the the triangles in the terrain very quickly.

Comment: you have any reference/ algorithm on this?

Comment: @Ngu - not to hand, sorry. It's been a while since I've done any serious 3D graphics, so I'd just be Googling for things like "octree" and "triangle line intersection" to get the up to date stuff.

Answer (score 0):

If the terrain is not built via a nice function you will have to do a [ray trace](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ray_tracing), i.e. traverse the line step by step in order to find an intersection. This procedure can take some time.

There are several parameters for the procedure. E.g. there is the offset you walk alogn the line in each step. If you take an offset too large, you might leave out some "heights" of your terrain and thus not get the correct intersection. If the offset is to small, it will slow down your procedure.

However, there is a nice trick to save time. It's described [here](http://wwwcg.in.tum.de/Research/Publications/TerrainRayCasting) resp. [here](http://wwwcg.in.tum.de/Research/data/Publications/EG09AreasTerrain.pdf). It uses some kind of optimization structure for the terrain, i.e. it builds several levels of details the following way: The finest level of detail is just the terrain itself. The next (coarser) level of detail contains just a forth of the number of original "pixels" in the terrain texture and combines 4 pixels into one, taking the maximum. The next level of detail is constructed analoguesly:

```
     .             .       .    .
    ... .         ...     ..    .
  .......        ....     ..    .
 ........    =>  ....  => .. => .

 01234567        0246     04    0
                 1357     26    4

   fine   =>  =>   =>   =>  =>  coarse
```

If now the ray cast is performed, first of all, the coarser levels of detail are checked:

```
   /
  / 
 /.
  .
  .
  .
```

If the ray already misses the coarse level of detail, no finer level has to be examined. That's just a very rough idea how the optimisation works. But it works quite well. Implementing it is quite a bunch of work, but the paper is a good help.

Comment: Your third document is not viewable

Comment: Also, I'm not exactly interested in doing ray tracing, I'm just trying to find the intersection point, that's all.

Comment: 1) On my PC it's viewable without problems. 2) Ray Tracing is used to find the intersection point.

Comment: @Ngu - Ray tracing is just the name of the algorithm. You are tracing the path of a ray (your line). In this case you only do it once. In the more familiar usage (for imagery) you do it for every pixel in the scene.

Comment: @ChrisF, but wouldn't that mean that I have to check each and every single grid cell to see whether there are intersections?

Comment: @phimuemue, I've read your answer above a second time, and it's now clearer. One thing I would like to ask though, is that for preliminary investigation, you try to use coaster pixel with a few finer pixels combined together, and take the max as the height. But this in really the coarser pixels may cover terrain that are ups and downs, and the ray may in reality already hit the terrain, but the coarser pixel won't show it.

Comment: @ Ngu Soon Hui, I think the coarser pixels indicate the hit, because they are constructed using the maximum of the underlying pixels. And if the ray misses the highest point, how will it then hit any point that is below the highest point? I had problems imagining it, but I did some drawing that clarified my thoughts on that. The only issue is that you do not skip some pixels - but the paper also provides a method to prevent this.

Comment: @phimuemue, I've no problem in imagining how a ray can miss the highest point, but still it hit the real point because the real point is lower than the highest point.