# Plane to intersect with terrain algorithm

Tags: c#, graphics

I have a terrain, which is represented by elements and coordinates ( they are just a list of mesh), and I have a plane.

How to find the intersection between the plane and the terrain? Should I just break the plane up into a list of lines, and then use ray casting technique or other technique to compute the list of intersection, and join them up together? Or is there other ways of doing?

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3252717/on-a-3d-terrain-given-a-3d-line-find-the-intersection-point-between-the-line-an) is a special case of my question here, in which I actually discretized the plane by breaking it into a lot of lines, and find the intersection points in order to get the lines where the plane intersect with the terrain, but I really wonder is there a better method.

Answer (score 0):

1. define the plane using its implicit equation. Find a, b, c, and d so that ax + by + cz + d = 0 for all (x, y, z) on the plane
2. Go through every square that defines a segment of your terrain. Interpret the square as two separate triangles
3. For each vertex v1 = (x1, y1, z1), v2 = (x2, y2, z2), v3 = (x3, y3, z3) of a triangle, determine which side of the plane it lies on:

   - l1 = a*x1 + b*y1 + c*z1 + d
   - l2 = a*x2 + b*y2 + c*z2 + d
   - l3 = a*x3 + b*y3 + c*z3 + d
4. Now there are two options.

   - either l1, l2, l3 are all > 0 or l1, l2, l3 are all < 0 - in that case the plane does not intersect the triangle and you have nothing to do.
   - or two of the l values are positive/negative and the third one is the opposite, e.g. l1>0, l2>0 and l3<0 - then the triangle edges v1-v3 and v2-v3 are being intersected
5. edge-plane intersection is easy to calculate. Assuming the v1-v2 edge is intersected:

   - xi = (x1*l1 - x2*l2)/(l1 - l2)
   - yi = (y1*l1 - y2*l2)/(l1 - l2)
   - zi = (z1*l1 - z2*l2)/(l1 - l2)

This way you will obtain a list of edges that correspond to intersection of the plane with your terrain. It is a slow method, but easy to explain... if you wanted to speed it up, you would need to use octrees or similar data structure to limit the amount of point/plane tests you need to do.